# jquery-like HTML parsing in Python?

Tags: python, jquery, css-selectors, html-parsing

Is there any way in Python that would allow me to parse an HTML document similar to what `jQuery` does?

i.e. I'd like to be able to use **CSS selectors syntax** to grab an arbitrary set of nodes from the document, read their content/attributes, etc.

Comment: latest [BeautifulSoup has support for css-selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62435195/1207193) now

Answer (score 65, accepted):

If you are fluent with [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup), you could just add [soupselect](http://code.google.com/p/soupselect/) to your libs.
Soupselect is a CSS selector extension for BeautifulSoup.

Usage:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
from soupselect import select
import urllib
soup = Soup(urllib.urlopen('http://slashdot.org/'))
select(soup, 'div.title h3')
```

```
    [<h3><span><a href='//science.slashdot.org/'>Science</a>:</span></h3>,
     <h3><a href='//slashdot.org/articles/07/02/28/0120220.shtml'>Star Trek</h3>,
    ..]
```

Comment: This sounds like the best solution for me right now, I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: It's now `from bs4` for Beautiful Soup 4

Comment: In case you have problem to install soupselect, you should try the pip compatible version offered her https://github.com/syabro/soupselect : `sudo pip install https://github.com/syabro/soupselect/archive/master.zip`

Comment: Just to mention, Beautiful Soup 4 already incorporates the soupselect project having built-in support for CSS selectors. See the [release note](http://www.crummy.com/2012/03/14/0).

Answer (score 50):

Consider PyQuery:

http://packages.python.org/pyquery/

```
>>> from pyquery import PyQuery as pq
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> import urllib
>>> d = pq("<html></html>")
>>> d = pq(etree.fromstring("<html></html>"))
>>> d = pq(url='http://google.com/')
>>> d = pq(url='http://google.com/', opener=lambda url: urllib.urlopen(url).read())
>>> d = pq(filename=path_to_html_file)
>>> d("#hello")
[<p#hello.hello>]
>>> p = d("#hello")
>>> p.html()
'Hello world !'
>>> p.html("you know <a href='http://python.org/'>Python</a> rocks")
[<p#hello.hello>]
>>> p.html()
u'you know <a href="http://python.org/">Python</a> rocks'
>>> p.text()
'you know Python rocks'
```

Answer (score 14):

The [lxml](http://lxml.de/) library supports [CSS selectors](http://lxml.de/cssselect.html).

Answer (score 10):

#### [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), now has support for **`css selectors`**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
html = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051295').content
soup = Soup(html)
```

Title of ***this*** question

```
soup.select('h1.grid--cell :first-child')[0].text
```

Number of question upvotes

```
# first item 
soup.select_one('[itemprop="upvoteCount"]').text
```

*using [Python Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) to get the html page*