# Server-side jquery

Tags: jquery, node.js, server-side

Say I have a script written in perl or python.  What's the easiest way to write a function that would use jquery selectors on strings as part of it?  i.e. to be able to do:

```
jquery_selector('table.new#element', text)
```

where `jquery_selector` is a function that runs a jquery selector on the html string stored in `text`.  Even if it was just limited to returning strings (not full jquery objects), it would still be really useful.  i.e. if you were required to give a javascript function as a callback which would render the results to something comprehensible in the scripting language:

```
jquery_selector('table.new#element, text, 'function(e){return e.val()}')
```

And it would return the results of the callback as a list.

I realize that there are dom libraries for most languages, but jquery is so much better than most of them.

I am not asking about native libraries which have a syntax like jquery.  I guess what would be needed is an API to a browser which jquery would run on?  Or is this what node.js does?

Comment: For meteor 1.0, and slightly different approach http://stackoverflow.com/a/26721055/1197775

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if i understand your question correctly you want is something like [phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org/). PhantomJS is a headless WebKit with JavaScript API. you can inject jquery into it and use all the jquery selectors to manipulate the dom. you can make it work like a standalone server aswell.

Comment: Knowing they're called *headless browsers* is half the battle. There's also [Zombie.js](http://zombie.labnotes.org/) for node.js.

Comment: @Jared Farrish zombie.js is a testing frame work but there is a phantom node module.https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node

Answer (score 0):

I am confused as you have tagged the question with "node.js" though you refer to Python or Perl in your question. Running node.js and/or phantom.js just to run a selector on an HTML DOM sounds quite heavyweight to me, and as always introducing whole chains of dependencies should be considered carefully in real-world projects.

So for Python I would suggest running a combination of [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup) and [soupselect](https://code.google.com/p/soupselect/), as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3051389/171579). You can then do things like:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as Soup
from soupselect import select
import urllib

soup = Soup(urllib.urlopen('http://slashdot.org/'))
select(soup, 'div.title h3')
```

Note that soupselect seems to implement only a subset of jquery's CSS3 selectors, so for things like e.g. sibling selectors or pseudo-classes it may not work. In this case I would advise to consider porting the relevant part of the project to node.js were you can run [Sizzle](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-sizzle) (jQuery's selector engine) or [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) standalone in a somewhat lightweight environment.