# jQuery error on Meteor.server: ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: jquery, meteor, meteorite

I'm getting this error after trying to use jQuery'a $.inArray() in a Meteor app's server folder. Is it possible to use jQuery on meteors server.js files?

If I'm not able to use jQuery methods on server-side, what is a good alternative? I currently found a work-around using underscore, but underscore has a jquery dependency, so I'm confused how jQuery gives me an error, but underscore works.

Comment: isn't it indexOf() working?

Comment: [Lo-Dash](http://lodash.com/) provides a very nice collection of functions, [`_.contains()`](http://lodash.com/docs#contains) being one of them.

Comment: Tomalak, I have just installed the mrt package for underscore, and that seems to be working.  Why do you recommend Lo-Dash over Underscore?

Answer (score 0):

Underscore comes shipped with meteor: Meteor uses it.

If you want to use JQuery on the server, try Phantom.js. See [Server-side jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255230/server-side-jquery)

Comment: Phantom.js seems like massive overkill if OP just wants to access jQuery's helper methods.