# Regular expression for html tags

Tags: regex

Hey this is the exact piece of code, that I have being working on and I need to capture this content:

1. On Air: Live at the BBC, Vol. 2
2. The beatles
3. 2013
4. Pop/Rock

I have been trying to write a regular expression for this and I can't get it all correct.
I think it's some problem with the div-tag and ahref-tag being not in a same line.May be, I am not sure.
Please help...I need a regular expression for this.
Thanks.

```
<div class="title">
            <a href="http://www.allmusic.com/album/on-air-live-at-the-bbc-vol-2-mw0002581064" data-tooltip="{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;MW0002581064&quot;,&quot;thumbnail&quot;:true}">On Air: Live at the BBC, Vol. 2</a>            </div>

                <div class="artist">
                <a href="http://www.allmusic.com/artist/the-beatles-mn0000754032">The Beatles</a>            </div>

                <div class="year">
            2013            </div>

                <div class="genres">
            Pop/Rock            </div>
```

Comment: You [should not parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3764814). There are more reliable ways. What's your language?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Python

Comment: Can't you use the HTML Parser in Python?
https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html

Comment: I don't know python, but I know I'd go for a jQuery-like lib in other languages, and the python equivalent is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051295/jquery-like-html-parsing-in-python)

Comment: Yeah @Jontatas answered about the HTML parser in Python. Thanks both of u :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Please [don't try to parse arbitrary HTML with regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use a proper HTML parser instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could perhaps use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''
    <div class="title">
        <a href="http://www.allmusic.com/album/on-air-live-at-the-bbc-vol-2-mw0002581064" data-tooltip="{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;MW0002581064&quot;,&quot;thumbnail&quot;:true}">On Air: Live at the BBC, Vol. 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="artist">
        <a href="http://www.allmusic.com/artist/the-beatles-mn0000754032">The Beatles</a>
    </div>
    <div class="year">
        2013
    </div>
    <div class="genres">
        Pop/Rock
    </div>
    '''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for s in soup.find_all("div", ["title","artist","year","genres"]):
    print(s.text.strip())
```

Outputs:

```
On Air: Live at the BBC, Vol. 2
The beatles
2013
Pop/Rock
```

Comment: I didn't even know you could pass a list as the second parameter for `find_all` awesome