# JQuery/CSS selectors in Python?

Tags: python, css-selectors, html-parsing

I parse HTML with Python.

After parsing I search for some elements in the tree.

I found no easy to use way to find elements in the tree up to now. XPath is available, but I prefer a familiar way.

Is there a way to use selectors in Python which have a syntax similar to jquery/css selectors?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jquery-like HTML parsing in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051295/jquery-like-html-parsing-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is library called pyquery: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery

Here is an example from the docs:

```
>>> d = pq("<option value='1'><option value='2'>")
>>> d('option[value="1"]')
[<option>]
```

Answer (score 5):

[`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) has CSS selectors support *built-in*:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> from urllib2 import urlopen
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen("https://google.com"))
>>> soup.select("input[name=q]")
[<input autocomplete="off" class="lst" maxlength="2048" name="q" size="57" style="color:#000;margin:0;padding:5px 8px 0 6px;vertical-align:top" title="Google Search" value=""/>]
```

There is also [`cssselect` package](http://cssselect.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that you can use in combination with [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/).

Note that there are certain [limitations in how CSS selectors work in `BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) - `lxml`+`csselect` support more CSS selectors:

> This is all a convenience for users who know the CSS selector syntax.
>   You can do all this stuff with the Beautiful Soup API. **And if CSS
>   selectors are all you need, you might as well use lxml directly: it’s
>   a lot faster, and it supports more CSS selectors.** But this lets you
>   combine simple CSS selectors with the Beautiful Soup API.

Comment: I get: `AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._Element' object has no attribute 'cssselect'` I use lxml version 3.3.3

Comment: @guettli could you update to 3.4.4 and try again? Also, what code are you executing?

Comment: This is a new question: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32264533/lxml-cssselect-attributeerror-lxml-etree-element-object-has-no-attribute

Comment: @guettli yeah, `lxml.html` has CSS selecting feature. If you are parsing html, you should use `lxml.html` and not `lxml.etree`.

Comment: I don't know if this is new, but now I have to install `cssselect` through pip in order to follow this answer

Comment: @Hubro yeah, `cssselect` was a part of `lxml` and now is a separately installed package - updated the answer accordingly. Thanks for the heads up!