# lxml: cssselect(): AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._Element' object has no attribute 'cssselect'

Tags: python, css-selectors, lxml

Can someone explain why the first call to `root.cssselect()` works, while the second fails?

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
from lxml import etree

html='<html><a href="http://example.com">example</a></html'
root = fromstring(html)
print 'via fromstring', repr(root) # via fromstring <Element html at 0x...>
print root.cssselect("a")

root2 = etree.HTML(html)
print 'via etree.HTML()', repr(root2) # via etree.HTML() <Element html at 0x...>
root2.cssselect("a") # --> Exception
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/foo_eins_d/src/foo.py", line 11, in <module>
    root2.cssselect("a")
AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._Element' object has no attribute 'cssselect'
```

Version: `lxml==3.4.4`

Comment: I added a feature request to lxml: https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxml/+bug/1490451

Comment: Just for the recorsd: The maintainer of lxml works fast. The feature request was implemented: https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxml/+bug/1490451

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is in the type of element. Example -

```
In [12]: root = etree.HTML(html)

In [13]: root = fromstring(html)

In [14]: root2 = etree.HTML(html)

In [15]: type(root)
Out[15]: lxml.html.HtmlElement

In [16]: type(root2)
Out[16]: lxml.etree._Element
```

[`lxml.html.HTMLElement`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.html.HtmlElement-class.html) has the method `cssselect()` . Also, `HTMLElement` is a subclass of `etree._Element` .

But the [`lxml.etree._Element`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html) does not have that method.

If you want to parse html, you should use `lxml.html`.

Comment: Is there a reason why cssselect() does not work on xml? I parse xml and would like to use css selectors instead of xpath. I can type css selectors fast since I use them often in jquery. While using xpath, I need to look up the reference every time :-(

Comment: because xml does not have a concept of css/cssselectors work based on specific attributes like `class` `id` `style` etc , xml does not have these kinds of attirbutes predefined , xml can have attirbutes. cssselectors only work on html.

Comment: Also, xpath is not that slower than cssselect, for the css selector `'a'` you can give xpath as - `'//a'` .

Comment: XML has the attribute `id`. Most CSS selectors would work very well with xml. Example: mytag[myattr="myval"]

Comment: I do care a lot of speed. For me it is the most important part of software development. But I guess we talk about a different speed. For me the time to get it done is **speed**.

Comment: the equivalent xpath for that would be `//mytag[@myattr="myval"]` . Not much difference.

Comment: Also, I am not the one who is designing/defining anything, it is like that. Given in this link - http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp - *CSS selectors are used to "find" (or select) **HTML elements** based on their id, class, type, attribute, and more.*

Comment: Also on a side node , you can still parse XML with lxml.html .